# Loading class defined in a string

Tags: classloader

Is there a means to load a class defined as a string?

Example API

`string classDef = "class MyClass { private int myVar; public setMyVar(int var) { myVar = var }}"
Class c = loadClass(classDef);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can compile and run Java code on the fly. See this blog post as an example: https://blog.frankel.ch/compilation-java-code-on-the-fly/#gsc.tab=0.

There might of course be all kinds of security concerns with compiling and running arbitrary code in your app.

Comment: thanks for the link. This is useful, but I'm looking for the code to be in memory (String, byte[]) and not in a file.